# Python `str` subclass not calling `__add__`

Tags: python, string, oop, python-3.6

I have a class that extends the python `str` class, essentially coded as follows:

```
class MyString(str):
    @staticmethod
    def str_wrap(method):
        def __internal__(*args, **kwargs):
            return_value = method(*args, **kwargs)
            print(method.__name__, type(return_value), *args, **kwargs)
            if type(return_value) is str:
                return MyString(return_value)
            return return_value
        return __internal__

    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        return_value = super().__getattribute__(item)
        if type(return_value) is str and item != "to_string":
             return MyString(return_value)
        if callable(return_value) and item not in ["to_string", "str_wrap"]:
            return self.str_wrap(return_value)
        return return_value

    def to_string(self):
        return str(self)
```

In my application, I have a line of code as follows, `new_str = (old_str + "." + os.path.sep)` where `old_str` is of the type `MyString`. The problem I'm having is that the type of `new_str` is `str`. In my `str_wrap` function, I have put code to trace what methods are being passed through it, and I noticed that `__add__` was never among them. Why is adding strings not calling `__add__` through `__getattribute__`? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `getattribute()` doesn't see dunder methods. You have to proxy them explicitly. (The accepted answer on Aran-Fey's link, incidentally, is mine, which uses a metaclass to do it automatically. But it was written for Python 2.x)